# "If Not _____ Is Nothing" and what it checks for

Tags: vba

Does this statement in VB check for the existence of the object, or does it check to see if the contents are null?  I'm thinking it's checking for the contents being null but I would like to double check.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using parentheses, for clarity in general:  `If Not ( ___ Is Nothing )`.  In some contexts this would prevent a problem with order of operations (though prolly not here, I admit).  I would also suggest you provide a few lines of context so we know what kind of `____` is `____`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The concept of "null" in VBA (in the sense of `NullReferenceException`-null, if you're familiar with C#, or `NullPointerException` in Java) is covered with the keyword `Nothing`. This holds true for VB6 (and earlier), as well as VB.NET.

```
Dim foo As Object
Debug.Print foo.Bar ' boom, the dreaded runtime error 91 shows up
```

So your interpretation of `Nothing` is correct.

Contrary to Java or C#, you can't use the comparison operator (`==` in C#/Java, `=` in VBA) to make a null-check in VBA, so instead (and in a way similar to SQL), you use the `Is` keyword:

```
If foo Is Nothing Then ' if (foo == null) { }
```

Or the negative form:

```
If Not foo Is Nothing Then ' if (foo != null) { }
```

Note that this formulation is invalid, because `Nothing` can't be negated:

```
If foo Is Not Nothing Then ' incorrect formulation, if (foo == !null) { }
```

---

Things get muddy and confusing when you realize that VBA has an `IsNull` function.... and then also `IsEmpty` and corresponding `Null`, `vbNull`, `Empty` and `vbEmpty` values - but these are outside the scope of your question, and are easily found on MSDN and Stack Overflow.

Comment: For better understanding I prefer this: **if Not (foo Is Nothing) Then**.