# Iframe inside iframe vba selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, iframe

i'm trying to parse data from a website https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp?matchday=2&daym=tomorrow but when i open stats for each league, shows me a ad frame. But sometimes doesn't appears and other times appears. And sometimes is an iframe inside other iframe, others is just inside one iframe. This is my code, but i don't know how i do my code to when doesn't appear iframe doesn't do  `.SwitchToFrame .FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@id='aswift_3']")`  , because when i do that shows me error.

```
                    .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@id='aswift_3']")
                    On Error Resume Next
                    .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@id='ad_iframe']")
                    .FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='dismiss-button']").click
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    .FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='dismiss-button']").click
                    End If
```

[image]

Comment: Set the iframe in a variable and test if Nothing. Base switchTo and subsequent steps according to that.

Comment: what? didn't understand sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919172/if-not-is-nothing-and-what-it-checks-for