# Slow VBA execution between Worksheet_Change and calling a UDF

Tags: excel, vba, performance, user-defined-functions

On a recent post ( [Dynamic Data Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76319996/dynamic-data-validation) ) I mentioned that the UDF runs slow, but I realized that the UDF executes in about 15 milliseconds using a QueryPerformance Microtimer - this is more than acceptable.

On the code below, placing `Debug.Print "Elapsed time (ms): " & Format((MicroTimer - startTime) * 1000, "0.000")` before line `Cells(Target.Row, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"` yields about 100 microseconds, moving the Debug line after the UDF line, yields 600 milli-seconds. 6000 times slower meaning there is a HUGE delay after triggering the UDF via FormulaR1C1.

I've measured the Worksheet_Change sub at various locations and it runs in the microsecond range - no issue here it seems.

The delay appears to be between the Worksheet_Change sub and UDF, but I'm not sure how to modify the timer code to measure time delays between subs. Any ideas on what could be causing this delay?
Could it be the `.FormulaR1C1 =` line itself?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim startTime As Double, ElapsedTime As Double
startTime = MicroTimer

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = Range("K22:K" & lastrow)
    Set rng2 = Range("S22:S" & lastrow)
    Set rng3 = Range("C19:C" & lastrow)

        If Application.Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then
            ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, rng1).Address = Target.Address Then
                If Target = "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, 12).Validation.Delete
                    Cells(Target.Row, 12) = ""
                ElseIf Target <> "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"
                    Debug.Print "Elapsed time (ms): " & Format((MicroTimer - startTime) * 1000, "0.000")
                End If
        End If

        If Application.Intersect(Target, rng2) Is Nothing Then
            ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, rng2).Address = Target.Address Then
                If Target = "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, 20).Validation.Delete
                    Cells(Target.Row, 20) = ""
                ElseIf Target <> "" Then Cells(Target.Row, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"
                End If
        End If
        
        If Application.Intersect(Target, rng3) Is Nothing Then
            ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, rng3).Address = Target.Address Then
                If Target = "" Then
                ElseIf Target <> "" Then
                    UpdateTheRibbon
                End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `Application.EnableEvents = false` at the beginning and `Application.EnableEvents = true` at the end of the sub.

Comment: Tried that, and all the typical application.xxx execution improvers - makes no difference though.

Comment: Not related to your question, but are you sure you mean `If Application.Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing` and not `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing` ?

Comment: You should definitely be disabling events anyway though since you are changing cells in a change event so your code will call itself unnecessarily.

Comment: @Rory - True, and yes it runs twice - first run is less than 100 microseconds, second run is 600= milliseconds. I left it like that because, on a different sub, the second run is actually required - but I guess I should rather look at optimizing that code instead and turn off events as suggested. Don't think that's the problem though.

Comment: @FunThomas - my understanding is that the only difference between those two is the double negative ```Not``` and ```is Nothing``` - my brain has trouble parsing that! Or is there a reason the double negative is widely used?

Comment: `Not.... Is Nothing` is easier to code than it is to say it's something in most use cases (with errors being thrown and the such if you try accessing something).  Mathieu Guindon [explains it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919705/19353309) on how to be less confused about it.

Comment: `Application.Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing` means that there is no common cell between target and rng1 (the modified cell is not part of rng1). As you likely want to check if the cell is within the range, you have to check that the Intersect "is something* - with other words "Not .. is Nothing"

Comment: Ok, I take that back, setting Application.Calculate to xlManual solves everything. Not sure how I missed that, probably because it needs to be on for the workbook to work, and setting it to xlAutomatic recalcs everything again which causes a longer delay of about 200 milliseconds. SemiAuto doesn't make a significant difference. The problem then I believe is the 120 991 Formulas in the workbook. 83 800 is on one sheet alone - I'll work on creating them when needed, instead of them just sitting there increasing execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Code can be made smaller without affecting speed. But by removing events, calculations and screen refresh I think there will be some difference in speed as well. The problem with the code you wrote is that it changes the values of some cells and inevitably before it finishes it is called again.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim c As Integer, startTime As Double, ElapsedTime As Double, lastrow As Integer, sRng() As Variant
   Dim rng As Range, rng3 As Range, emptyCell As Range, lookCell As Range
   
   If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then
      '?????????
      Exit Sub
   End If
   sRng = Array("K22:K", "S22:S")

   lastrow = Cells(Rows.CountLarge, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   
   'IN NEXT LINE CHANGE A1 WITH A CELL WHITCH REΜAINS EMPTY AND DON'T HAVE VALIDATION
   Set emptyCell = Range("A1")
   
   startTime = MICROTIMER
   
   On Error GoTo Lexit
   With Application
      .EnableEvents = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   End With
   
   With Target
      For c = 0 To 1   'Lbound(sRng)   Ubound(sRng)
         Set rng = Range(sRng(c) & lastrow)
         If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
            Set lookCell = .Offset(0, 1)
            If .Value2 = vbNullString Then
               emptyCell.Copy (lookCell)
               'COPY A CELL AS ABOVE OR USE NEXT TWO LINES
               'lookCell.Validation.Delete
               'lookCell.Value2 = vbNullString 
            Else
               lookCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DDDDL(RC[-1])"
Debug.Print "Elapsed time (ms): " & Format((MICROTIMER - startTime) * 1000, "0.000")
            End If
            GoTo Lexit
         End If
      Next
           
      Set rng3 = Range("C19:C" & lastrow)
      If Not Intersect(Target, rng3) Is Nothing Then
         If .Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            UpdateTheRibbon
         'Else
         End If
      End If
   End With
Lexit:
   With Application
      .EnableEvents = True
      ' .ScreenUpdating = True  ' DON'T NEED SET IT BACK TO TRUE
      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   End With
End Sub
```